# Social sharing toolkit is not showing on ajax load

Tags: plugins, social-sharing

I am using Social sharing toolkit (http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-sharing-toolkit/) in my website. 
This plugin is working fine with common posts but not working with ajax loaded posts.
Is there any fixes for this?.

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution:
Just added functions to call each buttons in the ajax loading JavaScript file.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    FB.XFBML.parse(); // For Facebook button.
    twttr.widgets.load(); // For Twitter button.
    gapi.plusone.go(); // For Google plus button.
});
```